# Multiple Vault connections with Spring Vault

Tags: spring-vault

I am using Spring Vault and need to connect to two Vault servers, one for secrets and another for transit operations. (My cluster has many more transit operations.) How can I setup Spring Vault (also using Spring Cloud Vault) for this configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Use dedicated `VaultTemplate` objects that are statically configured pointing each to a Vault endpoint that is intended for the particular use case.
2. Implement a routing `VaultEndpointProvider` along with a discriminator (e.g. `ThreadLocal`-based hostname). Each time you intend to call an action, you're setting the discriminator that is later evaluated by your `VaultEndpointProvider` to return the appropriate endpoint for your call.

Spring Vault uses a pluggable client model, with an upcoming version you'll be able to control `RestTemplate` creation and hook into `UriTemplateHandler` which would be the appropriate class to extend.